# Vulkan and ReShade64.json not valid errors

Tags: sdk, vulkan

I have done a fresh install of vulkan sdk and reshade because when i was trying to launch yuzu games from my command line i was getting errors regarding vk_initialization_error (failed to initialize GPU).

So i did a fresh install of vulkan and it was suggested that i install vulkan sdk. So when i run the configurator i get this error:

---

### Failed to load a layer manifest...

C:/ProgramData/ReShade/ReShade64.json is not a valid layer manifest.

Error #1
context: [layer][name]
desc:    Failed to match regex specified by 'pattern' constraint.

Error #2
context: [layer]
desc:    Failed to validate against schema associated with property name 'name'.

Error #3
context: 
desc:    Failed to validate against schema associated with property name 'layer'.

Total Error Count: 4

---

### The layer is being ignored.

### OK

So it was suggested that i reinstall reshade. Which i did. But i still get the same errors when I launch vulkan configurator. Is it a problem with my Reshade64.json file? The contents of which are this:

`{ "file_format_version": "1.0.0", "layer": { "name": "VK_LAYER_reshade", "type": "GLOBAL", "library_path": ".\\ReShade64.dll", "api_version": "1.3.204", "implementation_version": "1", "description": "crosire's ReShade post-processing injector for 64-bit", "device_extensions": [ { "name": "VK_EXT_tooling_info", "spec_version": "1", "entrypoints": [ "vkGetPhysicalDeviceToolPropertiesEXT" ] } ], "disable_environment": { "DISABLE_VK_LAYER_reshade_1": "1" } } }`

Thanks for any help!!!!

I reinstalled:

- vulkan
- vulkan sdk
- ReShade (not the addon version)

I was expecting it to work without errors. But I get errors.